# Change Wordpress URLs for Item Types and Items to replace item

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just purchased [Tour Operator WP Theme](http://www.ait-themes.com/wordpress-themes/touroperator-wordpress-theme/) and I'm running it on an internal web server (Windows 2012 with Wordpress 3.8).

I've set up Item Types as follows:

Sport
 - Swimming
 - Football

and have an Item called Water Palace that is in the Sport and Swimming Item Types.

If I view the Water Palace item the URL is like: `/item/water-palace/` but I'd like it to be `/sport/swimming/water-palace/` (if not then at least one of the Item Types instead of item). Is this possible?

The same for viewing an item type - URL is like: `/item/swimming/` but I'd like `/sport/swimming/` (or at least `/swimming/`). Is this possible?

I've read several other posts forums about changing the following line:

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'item') to 'rewrite' => array('slug' => '')`

but this made it worse replacing `/item/` in the URLs with `/ait-dir-item-category/` instead. I made the change in the file `\wp-content\themes\touroperator\AIT\Framework\CustomTypes\dir-item-tour\dir-item-tour.php` for both `aitDirItemPostType()` and `aitDirItemTaxonomies()` functions.

Am I missing something or is this not possible? Seems silly using `/item/` in the URL!

Trying to learn Wordpress so I can setup my own site....

Comment: Show us your PHP/Apache/IIS log from the internal server error.

Comment: There is no internal server error... it works, I just don't like the URLs. I want to change how they appear and Permalinks doesn't help here.